# clear scrollback buffer of Linux Virtual Console Terminals

Tags: linux, console, tty

I'd like to clear the scrollback buffer on Linux console VTs programmatically. i.e. not just clear the current visible screen, but the entire scrollback buffer, too. I.e. everything that after a clear screen would still be visible with Alt-PgUp should be gone too. Anybody got an idea how to achieve that in nice code?

Comment: Warning: this user is down-vote happy, answer here at your peril.

Comment: @richard: I love to live dangerously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is in mainline yet, but [linux-next](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git;a=commit;h=f8df13e0a901) has a patch to support a new console escape sequence that clears the screen *and* the scrollback buffer: [CSI 3 J](http://marc.info/?l=linux-man&m=130347970021684)

For something that works without having to upgrade your kernel, you can use:

```
chvt 42; chvt <current tty no>; echo -en "\e[1;1H\e[2J"
```

Alternatively:

```
echo -e "\e[12;42]"; sleep .01; echo -en "\e[12;<current tty no>]\e[1;1H\e[2J"
```

You can get the current tty number with:

```
$( ls -l /proc/self/fd | sed -ne 's/.*tty//p' )
```

Comment: It appears that simply `echo -en "\e[3J"` works now.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: yes, `\e[` is 7-bit `CSI`.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that other tools (over ssh for example) will have differing implementations of the "scrollback buffer". I highly doubt that you can clean the putty buffer by code in your machine.
Also see https://superuser.com/questions/122911/bash-reset-and-clear-commands

Comment: I care only about Linux *console virtual terminals*. Nothing else.

Comment: @user175104 which you did not specify in the question, but fair enough

Answer (score -1):

This clears the screen, but not the scrollback.

`echo -e '\0033\0143'` #depends on the terminal emulator you are using, tested on gnome terminal

from https://superuser.com/questions/122911/bash-reset-and-clear-commands